# Rails: Sending a reminder email if a condition is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking to send users of a product an email reminding them to do something if a certain condition is true.

Based on my knowledge so far, the following aspects are going to be involved:

**Script**: The code that needs to be executed (sending the email), and a condition that checks whether the email should be sent or not.

**Scheduling**: Execute the script once a day, using the gem whenever for easier creation of cron jobs.

Assuming this is true, I would do this:

1. Create a script consisting of an email incl. the condition whether the email shall be sent.
2. Create a cron job using whenever to execute the script.

Would that work? It seems to be that step one does not work, since I doubt you can set up the whole email in the script.

Can someone elaborate on creating a script that sends a message based on a condition?

*Bonus question*: How can I adapt a cron job to different time zones? Some users are from Europe and some from the States. Ideally, everyone should get the email at the same time in their timezone.

*I tried to write this question in an elaborative way so that other beginners on this topic who might run in to the same roadblocks have an easy way to follow.*

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way I can think of is to have a job run every hour that checks your condition, then sends an email to that user. You can use cron for this, or that gem whenever.

I would make this a rake task in your Rails application. That rake task's psuedo code would look something like this.

```
def remind_user_to_do_something
  users = User.get_users_based_on_condition
  // The above could be a scope defined on your User class.
  // Basically that scope would check 2 things
  // 1. Do I meet the condition you're talking about above.
  // 2. Is it time to send an email to them based on their timezone.
  for each user in users
    MyActionMailerClass.send_email_for_user user
  end
end
```